# insert static first row in cgridview yii

Tags: php, gridview, yii, dataprovider

my code in cgridview

```
    enter cod<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'party-ledger-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
             array(
                'name'=>'trans_date',
                'value'=> 'Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("d-MMM-y",strtotime($data->trans_date))'
            ),
                'trans_id',
                array(
                        'name'=>'tr_type_id',
                        'value'=>'$data->trType->tr_code'
                    ),
.....
```

and result shown below:

[image]

My question is how to insert first static row in cgridview table after header, for previous balance. how to add static custom row in cgridview.

Comment: view generated by cgridview widget, and dataprovider by model->search method in model, in controller call admin method that code generated by gii

Comment: can anybody post any answer to this question ?

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can't do this in simple way. There are 2 options:

1. Generating row in javascript and appending it to table.
2. using CArrayDataProvider instead of CAtiveDataProvider and appending to it first row that you will calculate. This method has more shortcomings.

I used first method when i faced this problem.

Comment: thanks alex to answer ,i tried to create a row with javascript but i need to be search and filter in gridview .