# Create Custom Row in yii Cgridview

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, cgridview

I had created a yii Cgridview but how to make custom row in the it. I want to make the custom row whose data is static not related to database?
the problem is similar to below

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/47751-insert-first-row-in-cgridview/

[insert static first row in cgridview yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182182/insert-static-first-row-in-cgridview-yii)

Comment: did you try domething?

Comment: @alex yes i tried to merge cactive dataprovider data and static data in search function of model but as i am new to yii so how i could make this possible ?and i cant get any answer on stack overflow.thanks for help in advance

Comment: why down point to this question

Answer (score 2):

Check this grid row

```
array(
    'name'=>'some_name',
    'value'=>'$data->getCountryNameOrStaticStringOrWhatever()',
),
```

In model

```
public function getCountryNameOrStaticStringOrWhatever(){
    return 'my static content or whatever';
}
```

Comment: thanks for help alex but actually i want a row for example i have two columns in my cgridview (id ,country_name) and data is fetched through cactivedataprovider from model but i have to insert static row in that grid view

Comment: so "data" - is static ctring there

Comment: i have to put 0 and allcountries in column id , country_name respectively

Comment: i updated answer, in model method getCountryNameOrStaticStringOrWhatever you can return whatever you need

Comment: one more update, you can always create your own GridColumn, but this method allows you to print anything

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182182/insert-static-first-row-in-cgridview-yii

Comment: can you please see the link i have some kind a similar query

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/47751-insert-first-row-in-cgridview/

Comment: i have exactly the above link query

Comment: i'll see, can you lease mark answer as decision (click on tick)

Comment: mark answer as decision mean ?i am new to stackoverflow also ?

Comment: alex i dont want a static column i want a static row

Comment: damn, my fault sorry, let me think

Comment: i have sent you two links you can go through it also?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with javascript and jQuery:

add `'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'addStaticRaw',` to CGrid config

and register js script:

```
function addStaticRaw(){
  $('#party-ledger-grid tbody tr:first').before("<tr><td>Your static raw blah blah</td></tr>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a similar solution and came across this:

`$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
             'id'=>'something',
             'dataProvider'=>$provider,
             'columns'=>array(
                     array(
                          'name' => 'name',
                          'header' => 'Name',
                          'footer' => 'name column for extra row',
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name' => 'email',
                            'header' => 'e-Mail',
                            'footer' => 'email column for extra row'
                        ),
                     )
                )`

Simply fill out the footer elements of each column with the data from you extra row.

It works like a charm!